# I am trying to build a sudoku solver and I am getting an error which says mixing iteration and read methods would mix data

Tags: python

This is the code:-

```
import sys

def read_file(textfile):
    f=open(textfile,'r')
    next(f)
    i=0
    j=0
    matrix=[[0 for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
    #print(matrix)
    while True:
        j=0
        char=f.readline()
        for c in char:
            matrix[i][j]=int(c)
            #print(i,j)
            j=j+1
            if j==9:
                i=i+1
                break
        if i==9:
            break
    return matrix

def check_soduku(row,column,number,matrix_board):
    check=0
    for i in range(0,9):
        if matrix_board[row][i]==number:
            check=1
    for i in range(0,9):
        if matrix_board[i][column]==number:
            check=1
    row=row-row%3
    column=column-column%3

    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if matrix_board[row+i][column+j]==number:
                check=1
    if check==1:
        return False
    else:
        return True

class calls:
    number_of_calls=0
c = calls()
def sudoku_solver(matrix):
    c.number_of_calls=c.number_of_calls+1
    break_condition=0
    for i in range(0,9):
        for j in range(0,9):
            if matrix[i][j]==0:
                break_condition=1
                row=i
                column=j
                break
    #print(matrix)
    #print(break_condition)
    if break_condition==0:
        print("Naive Backtracking Algorithm Solution: ")
        for i in matrix:
            print(i)
        print("Amount of Recursions")
        print(c.number_of_calls)
        exit(0)

    #print("hello")
    for i in range(0,10):
        if check_soduku(row,column,i,matrix):
            matrix[row][column]=i
            if sudoku_solver(matrix):
                return True
            matrix[row][column]=0
    return False

matrix=read_file(sys.argv[1])
sudoku_solver(matrix)

#print("'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''matrix'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''")
#print(matrix)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error stack trace? Thank you!

Comment: File "sudoku.py", line 76, in <module>
    matrix=read_file(sys.argv[1])
  File "sudoku.py", line 12, in read_file
    char=f.readline()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data     So this is the error it is displaying.I am using atom.I am very new to python...